# Wrong tag on document.execCommand('insertUnorderedList') in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using

```
document.execCommand('insertUnorderedList');
```

in my code.

In Chrome it works fine and inserts:

```
   <li>
    <a href="/example.html">example</a>
   </li>
```

But in Firefox the same command inserts:

```
        <li>
    <a href="/example.html">example</a>
*<br>*
    </li>
```

How could I preevent inserting this `<br>` tag?